Fastest way of removing outliers from a data set which depends on a variable
Edit: I meant $j\to\infty$...
Suppose we have the following code:
Clear["*Global`*"]
A[j_] := A[j] = 
 Range[0,j!]/(j!)
    S1[j_] := 
 S1[j] = Sort[Select[A[j], Boole[IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2]] == 1 &]]
S2[j_] := 
 S2[j] = Sort[Select[A[j], Boole[IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2]] == 0 &]]
Dist1[j_] := Dist1[j] = Differences[S1[j]]
Dist2[j_] := Dist2[j] = Differences[S2[j]]
NonOutliers[j_] := 
 NonOutliers[j] = Join[Dist1[j], Dist2[j]]

Question: How do we remove the outliers in NonOutliers within a short time? (For any constant $C>0$, the outliers is more than $C$ times above the interquartile range as j$\to\infty$. For this example, dist2 should be the outliers of nonoutliers.)
We need this to get an accurate NonlinearFit for larger values of j in List T
P[j_] := P[j] = NonOutliers[j]/Total[NonOutliers[j]]

entropy[j_] := entropy[j] = N[Total[-P[j] Log[2, P[j]]]]

T = Join[Table[{j, entropy[j]}, {j, 3, 30}], 
  Table[{10 j, entropy[10 j]}, {j, 4, 10}], 
  Table[{100 j, entropy[100 j]}, {j, 2, 10}]]

nlm= 
  NonlinearModelFit[
   T, {Log[2, aj^b + c], a < 1, a > 0, b > 1.5, b < 2.5, c > 0, 
    c < 1}, {{a, 1/3}, {b, 2}, {c, 2/3}}, j];

Show[ListPlot[T], nlm[j], {j, 3, 1000}]]

Edit: According to @JimB, I'm not looking for outliers but rather the "lack of fit". I don't know what measure of "lack-of-fit" or size I'm willing to tolerate. (As long as we end up removing dist2 in this case.)

Why do you think there are outliers in the first place?  You have an explicit function (rather than "real" data) so any "odd values" would suggest that something is wrong with the function and just getting rid of those "odd" values is just sweeping things under the rug.  Just running through a DeleteAnomalies function which just keeps the "good" values without one knowing what the algorithm does is not good science.

A plot of the data suggests that the first 3 function values and the rest of the values can't be summarized by a simple linear function in the logs of the predictor values.  That doesn't make the first 3 function values outliers.  If your objective is to produce a reasonable approximation of larger values of $j$, then just drop smaller values of $j$ that have no meaning for you.

@JimB Sorry for the late response. For every $j\in\mathbb{N}$, I want to delete outliers of nonoutliers  which approaches infinite times above the interquartile range as $j\to\infty$.

@JimB My current example isn't good enough but consider this example...A[j_] := A[j] = Range[0, j!]/(j!). (Note, in this case, all elements of dist2 should be an outlier as $j\to\infty$.)

You are confusing the concepts of "outliers" and "lack-of-fit".  You need to state the measure of lack-of-fit and the size of the lack-of-fit you're willing to tolerate.

I'm not sure what measure of lack-of-fit, nor size, to use. (As long as all of dist2 is eventually excluded as $j\to\infty$.)

Perhaps, we can do the following: delete element of nonoutliers[j] that are $C$ times the inter-quartile range, for any contant $C>0$, as $j\to\infty$.
